# How do I log in to Google Sheets using Java code?

Tags: java, google-sheets

I am trying to run a Java program according to the instructions from the official website:https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart
but I constantly get errors related to authorization through the downloaded JSON file credentials.

I've tried everything. And the service account and Oauth keys. Nothing works. Please, who made a similar program. Please write an algorithm for obtaining the correct JSON or post the correct one. Thanks!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:128)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:35)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets.getDetails(GoogleClientSecrets.java:82)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.<init>(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.java:197)
    at SheetsQuickstart.getCredentials(SheetsQuickstart.java:52)
    at SheetsQuickstart.main(SheetsQuickstart.java:70)
```

My JSON:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "java......",
  "private_key_id": "......",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "......@.......iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "......",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/......"
}
```

Comment: The link in your question is 404

Comment: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java#prerequisites

Comment: I tested the same credentials, but they work in Python code.